# Is it good practice to put global variables in AppDelegate.swift?

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a variable that I'll be using in several different view controllers, is that the proper place to initialize it?

These variables so far consist of an instance of NSUserDefaults (one view controller will be saving user preferences, another will be loading them) and an XML Parser (one class will call the parser, another will update the URL)

Comment: No create a struct/class preferably struct with static variables.That way you will be doing more like OOP.

Comment: Is it constants or not?

Comment: These variables so far consist of an instance of NSUserDefaults (one view controller will be saving user preferences, another will be loading them) and an XML Parser (one class will call the parser, another will update the URL)

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` already provides a singleton. There is no reason to provide access through a global on AppDelegate.

Comment: So I can initialize it in any view controller and use it in any other one? And I still have the parser as well

Comment: You shouldn't do XML parsing in view controllers. And with that, problem solved, no need for a singleton parser anymore. :) Seriously: the controllers should manipulate objects to display, not parse data, they should consume data that already has been processed by another class/whatever and made as objects.

Comment: Global Variables are generally [Considered Harmful](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful), anyway.

Comment: What would be a good approach to having one reference to a parser then?